# Mongoose createConnection promise

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bluebird

Is there some way I could return a promise from `createConnection`, so I don't have to use listeners

I'm using Bluebird for promises.

I'd like to use `.then()` and `.catch()` instead of listeners `.on('error', callback)` and `.on('open', callback)`

This is how I initialise the connection

```
_initConnection(connectionSettings){
    Mongoose.Promise = Bluebird;
    this.connection = Mongoose.createConnection(connectionSettings);
}
```

Comment: hi,could you provide more code, your current createConnection. Is it because you are connecting to several mongodb server?

Comment: @vdj4y i've updated the question

Comment: @Stevik: base on [mongoose document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html), `Promise` just for query. I think so

Answer (score 0):

Check out the page on [promisification](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html). From the docs:

*Promisification means converting an existing promise-unaware API to a     promise-returning API.*

*The usual way to use promises in node is to Promise.promisifyAll some API and start exclusively calling promise returning versions of the APIs methods.*

Specifically:

`var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"));`

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

Note that this possible since 4.4.0 ([changelog](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/History.md#440--2016-02-02))

Also, set mongoose's internal promise library to use bluebird like so:
`mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');`

EDIT 2:

Note also that you must use `mongoose.connect()` [cf](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-connect)

Answer (score 0):

[Mongoose.connect](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) returns a promise. Along these lines there is also a recent npm package that might be useful: [mongoose-connection-promise](https://github.com/stefanwalther/mongoose-connection-promise)

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose 5 supports promises on the `createConnection` method, but with some caveats.

> As for `mongoose.createConnection()`, mongoose still supports using the return value of `mongoose.createConnection()` as either a promise or as a connection.

```
// Works
mongoose.createConnection().then(conn => conn.model('Test', schema));
```

*For the caveats, check out the article.*

Source: https://thecodebarbarian.com/whats-new-in-mongoose-5-improved-connections

Comment: This code is deprecated for mongoose version 7+

Comment: Actaully, even version 6. The documentation says `Connections are not thenable, so you can’t do await mongoose.createConnection(). To await use mongoose.createConnection(uri).asPromise() instead.`